# Unable to upload the exported excel file to sql server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, telerik, rad

I am using the telerik rad controls in my asp.net web application. User can export any excel file say Test.xls. But when I try to import(Upload) Test.xls to Sql Server 2008. It gives error External Table is not in correct format. And the application crashes at the time of opening the Oledb connection. But if I create another Excel file say New.xls and import that file to my database, it works fine.

Can anyone help?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Not really much that we can say with so little information. Best guess would be that your excel column data mappings don't match those required by the database.

New.xls may be a red herring if it doesn't contain any data.

Try and give us a little more information please regarding data and the exception - have you looked at the actual exception data by running this in debug in VS? If so what is it?